# how to subtract months from date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what's the best way to subtract months from a date?

for example I get the following date 20220201 and I need 20220101 to be returned, I tried the following:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
month_a= str(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d') - relativedelta(months=1))
```

but the return is 2022-01-01, can you help me?

Comment: https://thispointer.com/subtract-months-from-a-date-in-python/ This may help you

Comment: see [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html#pyspark-sql-functions-to-date) and  [`add_months`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html#pyspark-sql-functions-add-months) function for pyspark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
month_a = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d') - relativedelta(months=1), '%Y%m%d')
```

strftime is a tool to convert date to a string with desired format

Answer (score 3):

The standard `str` representation of a `date` object is the format `%Y-%m-%d` (see **note**) so you need to format it correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import date

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d = date(2022, 2, 1)
last_month = d - relativedelta(months=1)

# need to specify %Y%m%d as your output format
print(last_month.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

And this outputs

```
#> python3 date_script.py
2022-01-01
```

---

Note - strictly speaking, `str` on a `datetime.date` is generated by `date.isoformat`, which returns the equivalent of `%Y-%m-%d`.

```
def isoformat(self):
        """Return the date formatted according to ISO.

        This is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

        References:
        - http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
        - http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html
        """
        return "%04d-%02d-%02d" % (self._year, self._month, self._day)
```